# How to remove image from cache with Volley?

Tags: android, image, caching, android-volley, networkimageview

I'm working on an app where the user is able to change his profile picture which is actually being stored in server like this: http://serveraddress.com/user-pictures/user_id , the problem is that as volley uses an Image Cache even after the user has changed the profile image (its uploaded to server), the cached image is being display instead of the "updated" image.

I tried to remove the image from the cache, and also to invalidate the image URL (because it's the same), but it's not working.

```
getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate("http://serveraddress.com/user-pictures/122432", true); //invalidate
mLRUCache.remove("http://serveraddress.com/user-pictures/122432");
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you ask for image? imageloader? NetWorkImage? ImageRequest?

Comment: I'm doing something like this: `mProfilePicture.setImageUrl("http://serveraddress.com/user-pictures/122432",mImageLoader);`

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Start a bounty, or did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. After a lot of research, I found that the way volley caches images on disk is according to the HTTP cache headers. If the cache headers say the image is still valid, then it will not be requested again from the server. And since the new image that you are storing has the same name, then volley will not request the image from the server. So, I applied this simple logic :

Lets say, initially your path of the picture is xxx.pic.jpg.

Obtain a random number, say x from any random number generator function. Simply append x to your profile picture path, i.e your new path of the image would be : xxx.pic.x.jpg. It should solve the problem :)